# how to move in iphone application to slide from left to right

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I have created a view in my view controller i want that when i load that subview or show that it may laod from left to right of the orignial view controller

```
 subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 125, 560,530)];

[subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:216./255 green:238./255 blue:209./255 alpha:1.0]];


UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(40,20, 169,42);
UIImage*btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.PNG"];

[backButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[subView addSubview:backButton];

[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

I want to open this view on button click i want that when button is clicked this view should come on screen sliding from left to right as normally new view controller opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 125, 560,530)];

[subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:216./255 green:238./255 blue:209./255 alpha:1.0]];


UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(40,20, 169,42);
UIImage*btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.PNG"];

[backButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[subView addSubview:backButton];

[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

On button click write code given below in function

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
subView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 125, 560,530);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Use this. hope helps

Comment: no is not happeig i want like the normally view controols flips to next screen

Comment: I had used this code several times it works. I think you have to set frame initially CGRectMake(320,0,320,480)
and then in animation set frame to CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)
you can also set animation time in place of 0.5 in seconds.

Comment: It is moving fast can we make it slow to look the animation

Comment: Write 1 or more in place of 0.5

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

Comment: write 1.0 or 1.5 or 2.0 in place of 0.5 to set the animation duration

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIView animation block

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.origin.y, subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height);
        subview.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(320.0, subview.frame.origin.y, subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height);
        subview.frame = CGRectMake(20, 125, 560,530);       
    }];
}
```